# How to show that in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ holds $(2,1+\sqrt{-3})(2,1+\sqrt{-3}) \subseteq (2)(2,1+\sqrt{-3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ideals

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Show that in  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ holds $$(2,1+\sqrt{-3})(2,1+\sqrt{-3}) = (2)(2,1+\sqrt{-3}).$$

The direction $\supseteq$ is clear since $(2) \subset (2,1+\sqrt{-3})$. However, I do not see how to do the $\subseteq$ part. I suppose we have to start as follows:

Let $x \in  (2,1+\sqrt{-3})(2,1+\sqrt{-3})$. By definition $x$ is a finite sum of products of elements in $(2,1+\sqrt{-3})$, i.e.

$$x = a_1b_1 + \ldots a_nb_n$$

for some $a_i,b_i \in (2,1+\sqrt{-3})$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We now want to show that $x \in (2)(2,1+\sqrt{-3})$. If I am not mistaken for every element $y \in (2,1+\sqrt{-3})$ holds $y = c+d\sqrt{-3}$ with $2 \mid c,d$. So if we can show that $x = e + f\sqrt{-3}$ with even $e$ and even $f$ we would be done.

But I do not quite see how to do that. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: You just need to show that the element $(1+\sqrt{-3})^2=-2+2\sqrt{-3}$ is also in the R.H.S.

Comment: @daruma: Thanks for your answer. I understand that indeed $(1+\sqrt{-3})^2 \in (2)(2,1+\sqrt{-3})$. But why should this prove the $\subseteq$-part? I do not understand that.

Comment: $w = 1+\sqrt{-3}\,\Rightarrow\, w^2 = \color{#0a0}{2w}-\color{#c00}4 \in (\color{#c00}4,\color{#0a0}{2w}) = (2)(2,w)\ \ $

Comment: @3nondatur, Since $(2,1+\sqrt{-3})^2=(2^2,2+2\sqrt{-3}, (1+\sqrt{-3})^2)$ and I hope it's clear the first two generators are in the R.H.S.=(2)(2,1+\sqrt{-3})=(2^2,2+2\sqrt{-3})$